# Concat all the columns from many files into one (in one line!)

Tags: python, windows, pandas

Open all the CSVs in a file (whom names are ending with a number),

Then get the column 'IMO' (in each file selected) to concatenate them into a 'df' dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(path + '/' + f) for f in all_names if f.split('_')[3][:-4].isdigit()]['IMO'])
```

But I want to do it in one single line (pure challenge nothing else)!

It's returning an error so far:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is the result of `print(all_names)`:

```
['AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q1_2009.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q1_2009_corrected.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q1_2009_corrected_short.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q1_2010.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q1_2011.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q1_2012.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q1_2013.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q1_2014.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q2_2009.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q2_2010.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q2_2011.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q2_2012.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q2_2013.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q2_2014.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q3_2009.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q3_2010.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q3_2011.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q3_2012.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q3_2013.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q3_2014.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q4_2009.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q4_2010.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q4_2011.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q4_2012.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q4_2013.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q4_2014.csv', 'a_few_boats_AIS.csv', 'unique_boat_names.csv', 'unique_ports.csv', 'unique_vessel.csv']
```

Comment: What is `all_names` and what condition are you checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pandas for filtering bad filenames and parameter `usecols` for filter only column `IMO`. `str[3]` in `pandas` not failed, but return `NaN` if `4.`th list does not exist.

```
#one line solution
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(path + '/' + f, usecols=['IMO']) for f in pd.Series(all_names)[pd.Series(all_names).str.split('_').str[3].str[:-4].str.isdigit().fillna(False)]])
```

It is same as:

```
s = pd.Series(all_names)
v = s[s.str.split('_').str[3].str[:-4].str.isdigit().fillna(False)]
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(path + '/' + f, usecols=['IMO']) for f in v)
```

Verifying:

```
all_names = ['AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q1_2009.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q1_2009_corrected.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q1_2009_corrected_short.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q1_2010.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q1_2011.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q1_2012.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q1_2013.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q1_2014.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q2_2009.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q2_2010.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q2_2011.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q2_2012.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q2_2013.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q2_2014.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q3_2009.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q3_2010.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q3_2011.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q3_2012.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q3_2013.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q3_2014.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q4_2009.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q4_2010.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q4_2011.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q4_2012.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q4_2013.csv', 'AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q4_2014.csv', 'a_few_boats_AIS.csv', 'unique_boat_names.csv', 'unique_ports.csv', 'unique_vessel.csv']

s = pd.Series(all_names)
v = s[s.str.split('_').str[3].str[:-4].str.isdigit().fillna(False)]
print (v)

0     AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q1_2009.csv
3     AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q1_2010.csv
4     AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q1_2011.csv
5     AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q1_2012.csv
6     AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q1_2013.csv
7     AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q1_2014.csv
8     AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q2_2009.csv
9     AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q2_2010.csv
10    AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q2_2011.csv
11    AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q2_2012.csv
12    AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q2_2013.csv
13    AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q2_2014.csv
14    AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q3_2009.csv
15    AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q3_2010.csv
16    AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q3_2011.csv
17    AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q3_2012.csv
18    AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q3_2013.csv
19    AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q3_2014.csv
20    AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q4_2009.csv
21    AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q4_2010.csv
22    AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q4_2011.csv
23    AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q4_2012.csv
24    AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q4_2013.csv
25    AIS_SIGHTINGS_Q4_2014.csv
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

My ultimate (working) version of this code is the following:

`df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(path + '/' + f,usecols=['IMO']) for f in all_names if f.split('.')[0][-1].isdigit()])`

I haven't tried your version but it looks like it should work just fine (if you fix the parenthesis problem though ;) ).
Thx for your answer.